# Appending Model into array in Swift

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, swift3, alamofire

So I have created a model class where I am using Alamofire to get data from an API. I want to display that data in the table to view so I was thinking of appending that model into an array in the VC and call it in the custom cell.

But I want to append that model into the array only if a key value matches a particular string.

However when I am using a simple if statement in the VC its giving me a fatal error saying bad instruction.

**Code**

Calling the Model

```
var notificationModel: NotificationModel!
var notification = [NotificationModel]()
```

viewDidLoad

```
if notificationModel.type == "meeting" {
    self.notification.append(notificationModel)
}
```

Model

```
Class NotificationModel

    var _type: String!

    var type: String {
        if _type == nil {
            _type = "Err"
        }
        return _type
    }

    func downloadData() {
          ... 
    }  
}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: How are you assigning the value for notificationModel ?

Comment: What is data type of "notificationModel.type"?

Comment: @AmanChawla You haven't initialized the `notificationModel`, you need to initialize it before accessing its property.

Comment: @NiravD i have in viewDidLoad by notificationModel = NotificationModel()

Comment: http://www.json4swift.com/ will be helpfull to create model.just give API data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have force unwrap NotificationModel. And you are trying to access type of a nil value.
Please try with the following fix.

`var notificationModel: NotificationModel!
var notification = [NotificationModel]()`

```
    if notificationModel?.type == "meeting" {
notification.append(notificationModel!)
```

}

Hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: data is not displaying coz its not executing the if statement because notificationModel is nil. so notificationModel?.type is also nil.

Comment: I am new to swift can you tell me how this should be done properly then?

Comment: you can use optional binding for notificationmodel and then check for type. Please follow link Swift.org